# Decoder PNG image in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, decoder, encoder-decoder

I the web server must be written in C#, which will come through http image with format PNG. The program must impose a filter on these images. The server will be multithreaded, it's van speed of processing.

In .NET is a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class, which already can impose filters. But I found that the conversion of bytes from the stream into a Bitmap takes a lot of time, I do

`var pict = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(imageStream)`

In .NET there are also `PngBitmapDecoder` class from the namespace system.System.Windows.Media.Imaging; But the decoding with it takes the same amount of time as with the Bitmap. According to the png Specification, algorithm decoder - Deflate.

Is there a way to decode an image faster than Bitmap and PngBitmapDecoder?

Comment: To confirm, are you using `System.Drawing`? Note that `System.Drawing` is a wrapper around GDI which is not particularly fast, furthermore GDI is not supported in non-interactive sessions such as web-applications. I recommend using the .NET Core version of ImageProcessor instead: http://imageprocessor.org/

Comment: Yes do System.Drawing. It was necessary to add to the question. 
Thanks for the link! I will read the documentation for the library.

Comment: Using `Image.FromStream` on a `MemoryStream` with a 160K 512x512 PNG I get an average of ~6ms to load.  What sort of performance are you expecting, how big are your images, have you profiled the method to find out what is actually taking all the time?